# How to put an element above two elements in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am have difficulty with some CSS. I'm trying to put an element above two elements. I've tried several solutions but nothing is helping.

```css
.grey_font {
  background-color: #FAF6EE;
  height: 280px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ads {
  background-color: #007181;
  height: 160px;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-left: 7%;
  margin-right: 7%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

footer {
  background-color: #00525D;
  height: 369px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav id="nav">
    <img src="Logo-horizontal.png" id="img_snark" />
    <ul id="tabs">
      <li>Qui Sommes-nous</li>
      <li>Blog</li>
      <li>FAQ</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
      <li id="compte">Mon compte</li>
    </ul>
    <img src="united-kingdom.png" id="uk_images">
  </nav>
</header>
<img src="Union.png" id="union_images">
<div class="images_first-plan">
  <div id="sentences">
    <img src="entree.png" id="entree_images">
    <img src="cake.png" id="cake_images">
    <img src="par Nicolas Cooking.png" id="nicook_images">
  </div>
  <div class="images-play">
    <img src="image 3.png" id="video_images">
    <img src="PLAY 1.png" id="play">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grey_font">
</div>
<div class="ads">
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

This is the case in picture :

[image]

When I put two elements in position 'fixed' or 'absolute'. They disappear.

This what I want:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you change your HTML? There is a better way to do this without positioning `absolute` or `fixed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the position to `absolute` then the width collapses. You need to set a width to make it visible and I also did the other positioning like below to meet your requirement:

```
.ads {
    position: absolute;
    width: 86%;
    left: 7%;
}

footer {             
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```css
.grey_font {
    background-color: #FAF6EE;
    height: 280px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.ads {
    background-color: #007181;
    height: 160px;
    z-index: 2;              
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 86%;
    left: 7%;
    display: flex;
}

footer {
    background-color: #00525D;
    height: 369px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
    <nav id="nav">
        <img src="Logo-horizontal.png" id="img_snark"/>
        <ul id="tabs">
            <li>Qui Sommes-nous</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>FAQ</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li id="compte">Mon compte</li>
        </ul>
        <img src="united-kingdom.png" id="uk_images">
    </nav>
</header>
<img src="Union.png" id="union_images">
<div class="images_first-plan">
    <div id="sentences">
        <img src="entree.png" id="entree_images">
        <img src="cake.png" id="cake_images">
        <img src="par Nicolas Cooking.png" id="nicook_images">
    </div>
    <div class="images-play">
        <img src="image 3.png" id="video_images">
        <img src="PLAY 1.png" id="play">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grey_font">
</div>
<div class="ads">
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add position 'absolute' to the element you need to flow, and also add 'top' and 'left' to control its position

```
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 0;
```

Then add position 'relative' for the upper main element you want to connect with

Answer (score 0):

as far as your html code is not complete and I couldn't figure it out which element is which, I name the div with search bar searchBox and the other one without search box, noSearchBox.

css:

```
.noSearchBox{
position:relative;
z-index:2;}

.searchBox{
position:absolute;
top:-8%

/*you should give a negative number to cross the parent top border which is 
noSearchBox and your number unit should be based on percent due to responsive 
reasons and if -8% was too much or not enough just give another number)
right: optional number, based on distance you want from right side and this one 
applies for left too.*/

z-index:3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Snark Factory</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <!-- Your header content here -->
    </header>
    <img src="Union.png" id="union_images">
    <div class="images_first-plan">
        <!-- Your content here -->
    </div>
    <div class="grey_font">
        <!-- Your content here -->
    </div>
    <div class="ads">
        <!-- Your content here -->
    </div>
    <footer>
        <!-- Your footer content here -->
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code -

```
/* Your other CSS styles here */

.images_first-plan {
    /* Other styles */
    position: relative; /* Add this to enable z-index */
}

.images-play {
    /* Other styles */
    position: relative; /* Add this to enable z-index */
}

.grey_font {
    background-color: #FAF6EE;
    height: 280px;
    position: relative; /* Add this to enable z-index */
    z-index: 1; /* Increase the z-index to bring it above other elements with lower z-index */
}

.ads {
    background-color: #007181;
    height: 160px;
    position: relative; /* Add this to enable z-index */
    z-index: 2; /* Increase the z-index to bring it above other elements with lower z-index */
    margin-left: 7%;
    margin-right: 7%;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: flex;
}

footer {
    background-color: #00525D;
    height: 369px;
    position: relative; /* Add this to enable z-index */
    z-index: 1; /* Increase the z-index to bring it above other elements with lower z-index */
}
```

> With these changes, the .grey_font element will appear above the other
> elements because its z-index is higher. Similarly, the .ads element
> will appear above the .grey_font element because its z-index is even
> higher.

Comment: Your paragraph is in a quote block; who are you quoting here? Who/what is the original source?

Answer (score 0):

If you can update your HTML, you can "fake" the overlay by wrapping the `.ads` element in a parent and setting the parent background to a `linear-gradient` with the same colors as the section before and the `footer` section.

I removed the unnecessary HTML elements.

```css
.grey_font {
  background-color: #FAF6EE;
  height: 280px;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* This creates a hard gradient with the stop in the middle to fake an overlay */
.ads-wrapper {
  background-image: linear-gradient( #FAF6EE 50%,  #00525D 50% );
}

.ads {
  background-color: #007181;
  height: 160px;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-left: 7%;
  margin-right: 7%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

footer {
  background-color: #00525D;
  height: 369px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grey_font">
</div>
<div class="ads-wrapper">
  <div class="ads">
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```